# REGEX Pattern for Camel case format starting with lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a validation in javascript that will  detect the input value is in camelcase format. The first letter expected to be lowercase.

I got some code from stackflow and made it in [JSFIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/k12sd4qk/1/)

Its working for both helloWorld and HelloWorld

I would appreciate if someone could help me to complete the task..

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "HeLloWorld";
var patt = new RegExp("[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*");
var res = patt.test(str);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Note: I have been playing around with it. So it will not be the correct regex.

Comment: [`^[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ4rQ6/1) - just add anchors. Or `\b` (`\\b` in the `RegExp` constructor) instead of `^`/`$`

Comment: What needs to be completed? By the way, do you consider `"foo"` to be camelCased?

Comment: let me confirm on that foo. But fooBar is camelcased

Comment: It worked @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not delved too deep into the pattern, but it seems working for your input only when you add the boundaries or anchors. The problem with matching `HelloWorld` is that your pattern matched `elloWorld` and `RegExp#test()` returned true.

```
^[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$‌​
```

Or

```
\b[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ4rQ6/1)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "HelloWorld";
    var patt = /\b[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*\b/;
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "HelloWorld match with word boundaries: " + res + "<br/>";
    var patt2 = /^[a-z]([a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]|[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "HelloWorld match with start/end string anchors: " + patt2.test(str);
}
```

```html
<p>The test() method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.</p>
<p>Click the button to search a string for the character "e".</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```